# Spring batch master is waiting but worker startup failed in remote partitioning

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am stuck in a scenario in spring batch job remote partitioning where master started successfully but worker failed to start.The job is deployed on Aws batch , so master is waiting indefinitely for workers to finish since worker cannot comeup.
Can anyone suggest me the way to handle such scenario. I dont want my master node to wait till timeout has occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manager is configurable with a timeout to fail if workers do not reply in time. So it won't wait indefinitely.

And if that happens, the job instance will fail and you can either:

- restart it (only failed partitions will be restarted)
- or abandon it and start a new instance.